RESTful API (Django) best practices for admin and normal user access
hello i am  working on mobile app that is show for the users to invest on properties and my question is when i implement the APis for the normal user and the admin am i need to make separate APIs for each app because the admin can see  and make all operations in the admin dashboard and the normal user can also see the list of all the properties  ,get the payment methods and so on.. but on the mobile app not on the admin dashboard
example :
1-admin dashboard :http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/api/properties-list/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/api/cart-list/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/api/cart-update/
and the rest of the APIs
2-mobile app :http://127.0.0.1:8000/mobile/api/properties-list/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/mobile/api/cart-list/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/mobile/api/cart-update/
and the rest of the APIs
is that is the best practice for ensuring that the normal user can access the list of the
properties from the admin dashboard ?
am i try to solve problem that facing me and my expected to have result for my question
